# xargs not functioning in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, copy, command

I am trying to use xargs for copying files after selecting them using this command

```
grep 'string' | awk '{print $2$3}' | xargs -I {} cp {} /dir1/dir2/dir3
```

I get the following error message per each file I am copying

```
cp: cannot stat `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.jpeg': No such file or directory
```

The problem that it is telling me the directory correctly, and telling me it is not found, the file1.jpeg is actually in the dir3 file and the whole route is 100% correct

I tried to use `echo cp` and I still get this message per file:

```
cp /dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.jpeg /new/directory/
```

Can anyone help?
-Appreciated

Comment: Do you want to cp file from /dir1/dir2/dir3 or to that directory?

Comment: Yes Roger, multiple files actually

Comment: You didn't get my question, I want to ask /dir1/dir2/dir3 is the source directory or destination directory?

Comment: dir1/dir2/dir3 is the source directory, I am copying to /new/directory

Comment: You should put {} after /dir1/dir2/dir3

Comment: Oh I tried this before (and now again), I get the exactly the same error. cp: cannot stat `dir/1............` no such file or directory.

Comment: What's the output of "grep 'string' | awk '{print $2$3}'"?

Comment: dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.jpeg - dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.jpeg -dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.jpeg (each on a new line)
and so on :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30990/discussion-between-roger-and-error404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `grep` and `awk` and use `find` along with `xargs`.

Something like this:

```
find /path/to/search/ -type f -iname "*string*" | xargs -0 cp -t /path/to/copy
```

You can also use `exec` option of `find` and avoid `xargs`.

Comment: It is not actually a /path/to/search, it is a result of a previous diff command, I tried to put it this way `diff folder1 folder2 | find find -type f -iname "*string*".....` and I got these 2 error messages. find: ‘./.config’: Permission denied. xargs: argument line too long